# Pattern match with variable parameters

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Please suggest best was to implement the below code:

**Requirement**: pass single string or no parameters

```
object Twofer {
  def twofer(name: String*): String = name match {
    case Seq(nm) => s"One for $nm, one for me."
    case List() => "One for you, one for me."
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to achieve. If your problem is that your cases are not matched, just do `name.toList`, because type of `String*` is really `WrappedArray`.

Comment: Why don't use just use `def twofer(name: Option[String])`, which is either a single string or `None`, instead of doing a `vararg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something similar to the following:

```
def twofer(names: String*): String = List(names: _*) match {
  case Nil => "No names!"
  case n :: Nil => s"Single name $n"
  case ls => s"Multiple names $ls"
}
```

Comment: Conversion to list is unnecessary. `case Seq() => 0; case Seq(a) => 1; case _ => 123` seems to work just as well. Anyway, I don't know what it has to do with the question.

Comment: I assumed OP was seeking an alternative solution.  While OP's solution works, pattern matching `varargs` with a `Seq` seems less intuitive (wouldn't even assume it would for sure work before actually testing it) than with a collection with the `splat` operator.  I also intended to showcase matching a List with the `cons` operator along with a default case that could be further expanded to handle more specific cases.